# Linking two hardware serial ports

Tags: hardware, tty

I have two micro-controllers which are connected to my computer(ubuntu 12.04) through serial-USB cables.
One of the controllers (ttyUSB0) is programmed such that it sends data serially and another (ttyAMC0) is programmed to receive data serially.

So please any one could guide on achieving a link(send the data available at ttyUSB0 to ttyAMC0 ) between these two hardware ports.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What about a very simple `cat </dev/ttyUSB0 >/dev/ttyAMC0`?

Comment: Yes I tried but no use... my controllers had been programmed to send and receive data at speed of 9600.. So should I again set speed of those ports using terminal commands??.. if yes how can I set speed n other configurations of the ports (ttyUSB0 n ttyACM0)...

Comment: You can set speed and other parameters with `stty`.

Answer (score 1):

Well, the obvious way is to connect the two ports to each other, using a serial cable, without the two USB/serial adapters. Since you're not doing that, I presume its because you want the computer to do something—for example, this would be a reasonably common setup for reverse-engineering the protocol between the two devices.

[Snooper](https://packages.debian.org/jessie/snooper) is a program for just that: forward data between two serial ports, monitoring the communication.

Comment: Hello... Thank you for your reply .... but it is not working (I mean not able to receive data ), is there any other way to make this possible....

Comment: @VishnuKanth it's been a while since I've used the program, but please confirm all your serial settings are correct (bit rate, flow control, parity, etc.). Have you confirmed the parts work independently? (E.g., with minicom or whatever).

Comment: Thank you .... Its working now... made a silly mistake earlier... now its totally fine....

Comment: @VishnuKanth glad to hear that. You might want to consider accepting this answer; see the Help Center's [*What should I do when someone answers my question?*](http://unix.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this is going to help... but I found this:
https://superuser.com/questions/403331/how-do-i-link-two-serial-ports-in-gnu-linux

It suggest the use of socat with a link to this page:
http://technostuff.blogspot.be/2008/10/some-useful-socat-commands.html

The command is on top:

```
socat /dev/ttyS0,raw,echo=0,crnl /dev/ttyS1,raw,echo=0,crnl
```